# Accessing generic object passed into generic class

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, orleans

I'm trying to use a generic class to pass in a data object then uses the values within to complete CRUD operations.

```
class OrderState<TGrainState> : Grain, IState where TGrainState : class
{
    protected TGrainState State { get; set; }

    public Task Get()
    {
        using (var context = new SDbContext())
        {
            //Passing Null instance because not sure how to access the instance of the state object
            var test = typeof(TGrainState).GetProperty("id").GetValue(null);

            //int t = (int)test;
            //var obj = context.orders.Where(x => x.Id == t);
            //return Task.FromResult(obj);
        }


        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

TGrainState is the generic object I want to pass in.

```
public class State
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string AssignedOrganization { get; set; }
    public bool isComplete { get; set; }
    public string assignedUser { get; set; }
}
```

This is the state class I'm attempting to pass into the generic class.

```
class OrderGrain : OrderState<State>, IOrder
{
    public override Task OnActivateAsync()
    {
        //Should fill the State Object from the Db
        Get();
        //Sets the information contained in the State to the Object
        this.orderInfo = new OrderInfo
        {
            Id = State.Id,
            Created = State.Created,
            AssignedOrganization = State.AssignedOrganization,
            isComplete = State.isComplete,
            assignedUser = State.assignedUser
        };
        return base.OnActivateAsync();
    }
}
```

Class that inherits from the State Generic class that contains all of the CRUD operations.

So what I'm more or less trying to accomplish is how Microsoft Orleans has it's state setup where you create a state object, operate on that, then call Write(), Update(), Delete(), or Get() to perform the CRUD operation on the DB with Entity Framework using the state data declared.

The question is when I try to access the Values of the properties of the State object (State) inside the generic class (OrderState) I get the Error

> System.Reflection.TargetException: 'Non-static method requires a
>   target.'

Link to the Orleans information that i'm trying to mimic.
[Microsoft Orleans Grain Persistence](https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Documentation/Core-Features/Grain-Persistence.html)

I might thinking about this wrong or just be completely wrong, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: I'm assuming by "access the values" you mean invoke the getter.  If you are invoking an instance method/getter/setter/whatever, you need an instance to invoke it by.  You are passing "null".  That works for static methods/getters/setters, but not for instance ones.  Your code doesn't make it easy to tell what you are trying to do.  But whose ID are you trying to get

Comment: @Flydog57 Yeah that's the problem I'm facing. In Microsoft Project Orleans you create a class that extends the generic grain class that you pass your state object within for persistence state. Then update the information within the class and call a method such as WriteStateAsync thats within the generic grain class, which uses the State object to perform it's write to the DB. That's what I'm trying to copy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that this is a simple case of case-mismatching (pun not intended).

In this line:

```
var test = typeof(TGrainState).GetProperty("id").GetValue(null);
```

You are looking for the property `id`. However, your class declares it this way:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

The return value of the GetProperty method is "An object representing the public property with the specified name, if found; **otherwise, null**." Invoking GetValue on a null instance would result in the exception you're seeing.

Comment: I get what your saying and that makes sense, but how would I go about getting the instance at that point since it's not really instantiated within the OrderState Class, the Instance would be within the OrderGrain class.

Comment: The rest of your code doesn't make any sense.  Your "State" class has a whole bunch of non-static properties, but you have code like: Id = State.Id.  That doesn't compile, does it?  You need to have an instance of TGrainState hanging around somewhere for any of this to work.  Please don't post "doesn't compile" code unless you say "this doesn't compile".  Once you get this so there's an instance of TGrainState, you can constrain it to an interface that has an ID property and go to town with no reflection needed

Comment: You can use `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TGrainState))` to create your instance and then pass that instance to `GetValue`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 . If you add the `new()` generic constraint to `TGrainState` then you can also just use `new TGrainState()` to create the instance. And you call GetValue with `.GetValue(this.State)`.